# Git branch -r missing a branch name

Tags: git

I am very new to git and its command. Here in my case client already created a branch and ask me to work on the same branch ,Then the following command I triggered.

```
dev@PGIVM01:~/repository/anp-air$ git checkout 0012.6_cmip_pga
error: pathspec '0012.6_cmip_pga' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Then I tried git branch -a and git branch -r in both cases I can't find the remote branch name 0012.6_cmip_pga .

Then I tried the fetch command
git fetch --all

git fetch -r

This time the branch name they specified listed. 
I have a doubt like how git branch -r missed the branch name first? What is the actual purpose of the fetch command. Help me

Comment: do `git fetch origin` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything on Git happens locally, on your local repository. When your repository is linked to a `remote` repo, there are only two operations that you use to communicate with your remote:

`git fetch` - Asks for a delta from all commits, branches, tags and whatsoever **that your remote has and you don't**, and updates the local references on your local repository.

`git push` - Sends out a delta from all commits from a given local branch, **that you have and your remote doesn't**.

The `git branch` command you issued is resolved locally (it won't actively talk to your remote), that's why didn't indicate the remote branch without you actually fetching it first.

Comment: On a side note, `git pull` is barely a shorthand for a `git fetch` + `git merge`

Answer (score 0):

By `git fetch` command your local history is updated with the remote history ( like branches, commits, tags, etc.) but not merged with local your working tree.

So, after `git fetch -all`, `git branch -r` or `git checkout <branch-name>` is working.